# C# error, member with same name

Tags: c#

I writed this code, but, when I try to build, the compiler returns:

```
1>code.cs(16,16,16,44): error CS0542: 'DataGridViewPercentageColumn': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type


using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace TestSample
{
    internal static class DataGridViewPercentageColumn
    {
        public class DataGridViewPercentageColumn : DataGridViewColumn
        {
            public DataGridViewPercentageColumn() : base(new DataGridViewPercentageCell())
            {
            }
        }

        public class DataGridViewPercentageCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
        {
            public DataGridViewPercentageCell()
            {
                this.Style.Format = "0%";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How I can solve this, and, why this error happens??

Thanks

Comment: The inner class `DataGridViewPercentageColumn` has the same name as the outer class.

Comment: No... o.O, there is not another class with the same name

Comment: `internal static class DataGridViewPercentageColumn` has same name as `public class DataGridViewPercentageColumn`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot nest two classes with the same names. Your inner class DataGridViewPercentageColumn has the same name like the outer class. You have to rename one of these classes like:

```
internal class DataGridViewClasses{
    public class DataGridViewPercentageColumn : DataGridViewColumn
    {
        public DataGridViewPercentageColumn() : base(new DataGridViewPercentageCell())
        {
        }
    }

    public class DataGridViewPercentageCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    {
        public DataGridViewPercentageCell()
        {
            this.Style.Format = "0%";
        }
    }
}
```

Btw: You cannot have any other members or properties inside a class named like the class itself.

Answer (score 3):

Your wrapper class has the same name as one of the internal classes.

The issue is `DataGridViewPercentageColumn`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you've defined a class within another class, both of which have the same name. Give the internal static class a different name.